# DidFinishLaunching problem in application of iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hello
I have problem with didFinishLaunching methods. I am really getting confused about what was the problem and that's why I pasted all my code. The problem was the application didn't launch, it crashed, and it show me this message in console:

```
**[Demo1AppDelegate setMapViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5649a30
2011-05-25 14:17:58.724 Demo1[10630:207] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Demo1AppDelegate setMapViewController:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5649a30'**
```

I am using this code 
In Demo1appDelegate.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface Demo1AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    UIWindow *window;
    MapViewController *mapViewController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;

@end
```

And in 
Demo1AppDelegate.m file

```
#import "Demo1AppDelegate.h"
@interface Demo1AppDelegate ()
@property (nonatomic, retain) MapViewController *mapViewController;
@end

@implementation Demo1AppDelegate

@synthesize window;


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    MapViewController *viewController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    self.mapViewController = viewController;

    [viewController release];

    [window addSubview:self.mapViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [mapViewController release];

    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Comment: It's Very good question. 1st Define the @interface Demo1AppDelegate () @property (nonatomic, retain) MapViewController  in demo1Appdelegates.h file and @sys into the .m file it will work

Comment: I already  try this but it is not working .It show same massage in console

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think

```
self.mapViewController = viewController;
```

is the problem. You do not have  `@synthesize` for `mapViewController`. So you cannot access through `self`

Or another option is to try this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc] init];
    [window addSubview:mapViewController.view];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: check it out this link https://github.com/elbryan/MapKitDynRoutes i am trying do the same think but it not work

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement UIApplication

change

```
@interface Demo1AppDelegate : NSObject
```

to

```
@interface Demo1AppDelegate : NSObject  < UIApplicationDelegate>
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: check it out this link github.com/elbryan/MapKitDynRoutes i am trying do the same think but it not work

Answer (score 1):

the problem is in this line `self.mapViewController = viewController;`

you forgot `@synthesize mapViewController;`

Comment: check it out this link github.com/elbryan/MapKitDynRoutes i am trying do the same think but it not work

Answer (score 1):

You have to `@synthesize mapViewController;` in Demo1AppDelegate.m

You should also add `[mapViewController release];` in the `dealloc` method of Demo1AppDelegate.m (with mapViewController being an instance variable).

Comment: almost - you should not use the accessor within dealloc

Comment: check it out this link github.com/elbryan/MapKitDynRoutes i am trying do the same think but it not work

Comment: @Till: true. Should have an instance variable. Was just a lazy response.

Answer (score 1):

Synthesize your map view controller.

Comment: check it out this link github.com/elbryan/MapKitDynRoutes i am trying do the same think but it not work

Answer (score 0):

Add delegate as follows ... This might be the issue :
`@interface Demo1AppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate>`

Comment: check it out this link github.com/elbryan/MapKitDynRoutes i am trying do the same think but it not work

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
@class MapViewController
```

before @implementation Demo1AppDelegate in Demo1AppDelegate.h

Comment: check it out this link github.com/elbryan/MapKitDynRoutes i am trying do the same think but it not work

Answer (score 0):

Hey!  Where you add the subview

```
[window addSubview:self.mapViewController.view]; [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Try without "self"

```
[window addSubview:mapViewController.view]; [window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Just a flying guess.

Comment: sorry...just saw the above answer...I written this answer but forgot to post it so just didn't spot the above Q.